# Count upper case along with lower case

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code and I am trying to sort through words and count the letters used and add them to a single array called count[26]. It works for counting lower case but it is not counting the upper case. What do I need to do in order to count the upper case along with the lower case.

```
/*                                                                              
 * Search through each character in s,                                          
 * which is array containing n strings,                                         
 * and update the global count array                                            
 * with the correct character counts.                                           
 * Note: check the examples to see                                              
 * if the counts should be case                                                 
 * sensitive or case insensitive.                                               
 */
void letterCount(char * s[], int n){
  //Implement this function                                                     
  int c = 0,x,i;
  char p = 'a', j = 'z';
  while (c<n) {
    for(i=0;s[c][i]!='\0';i++)
      if ((s[c][i] >= p && s[c][i] <= j)){
        x = s[c][i] - 'a';
        count[x]++;
      }
      c++;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
"BcdaADc"

A = 2
B = 1
C = 2
D = 2
E = 0
etc.
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a good time to make use of the functions already provided to you in **ctype.h**? Namely, the `islower` and `isupper` functions. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second "if" case within your for loop to check uppercase letters. You have initialized p and j to the uppercase range

```
char p = 'a', j = 'z';
```

And you determine the letter's index in your final array by subtracting a lowercase 'a'

```
x = s[c][i] - 'a';
```

Now do the same thing with uppercase! Remember, uppercase letters are totally different [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So initialize some chars:

```
char uppercaseA = 'A', uppercaseZ = 'Z';
```

add a second if statement (or combine this with the first if statement):

```
else if ((s[c][i] >= uppercaseA && s[c][i] <= uppercaseZ)){
```

and update your counts!

```
x = s[c][i] - uppercaseA;
count[x]++
```

PS: PLEASE start picking better variable names!! What is s? What is p? What is j? This code is very hard to read, which makes it hard to understand logically, for both yourself and others!

Comment: You are awesome, it worked. Also you are right about naming the variables, I really do need to work on that.